# How do I bundle CSS and js files into a single HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bundle, webpack

Is there a way `webpack` can process my HTML tags such as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

And bundle them into

```
<style>
  //contents of minified style.css 
</style>
<script>
  //bundled and minified script.js
</script>
```

So I can serve a single file from my servers? I managed to do this with the [Processhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml) grunt plugin, but I'm not using grunt as build system on this project.

Comment: Maybe [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) is worth a look? I have a feeling you could apply a couple of loaders within a template through it to pull this off.

Comment: try `GULP` its a built system for web applications.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with webpack using; extract-text-webpack-plugin, html-webpack-plugin and UglifyJsPlugin
there's also uglify loader if you want to uglify during bundling, as the plugin does the uglify after the bundle is created.

Answer (score 0):

`html-webpack-inline-source-plugin` should be what you're looking for. It is a plugin for `html-webpack-plugin` which itself is a plugin for `webpack`. So basically works as a plugin for a plugin for webpack. The [github page](https://github.com/dustinjackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin) shows a very simple example on how to do exactly what you're looking for.